# SE outgoing mailserver graylisting delay

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email

My private mail server uses graylisting as an anti-spam measure. Usually, mail servers try to re-transmit between 5 and 10 minutes. Stack Exchange mx-out, however, made the re-transmit after about 27 minutes, way off the 15 minutes noted in the sign-up page.

Answer (score 10):

So? I use graylisting too, I see plenty of mail servers use longer delays, you *did* just tell that MX that your server is 'overloaded' and to come back *later*.

That's not a *bug*, however, as there is no standard delay set in the SMTP RFCs. The MX is free to pick a re-delivery time, even if that is days later. The *15 minutes* mentioned on the sign-up page is aimed at *normal* email delivery delays, not accounting for graylisting.

If you care about Stack Exchange email arriving sooner, whitelist their servers (`mx-out.stackexchange.com`, IP addresses `198.252.206.125` (NYC) and `192.111.0.125` (Denver)). Or don't graylist DKIM-equipped MTAs; the `mx-out.stackexchange.com` server is properly authorised to send mail on their behalf.